# Listing data from database in hierarchic style

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, treeview, components, vb.net-2010

How i can list data field in this manner

[image]

Where the data i have scratched is coming from MS SQL database and the the one which i have not scratched is a static data i want to keep.

Is there any specific component for this in VB.NET or i need to get it from any third party vendor?

Is it called a tree view component or something else? I have searched a lot on internet but unable to find any solution for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is a treeview component. There are treeviews available within .Net, and numerous third party components of varying quality.  How you populate it depends on the component you choose, and the platform (winforms or web)